# Proper GROUP BY syntax

Tags: postgresql

I'm fairly proficient in mySQL and MSSQL, but I'm just getting started with postgres. I'm sure this is a simple issue, so to be brief:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  column "incidents.open_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

In statement:
SELECT date(open_date), COUNT(*)
FROM incidents
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY open_date
```

The type for `open_date` is `timestamp with time zone`, and I get the same results if I use `GROUP BY date(open_date)`.

I've tried going over the postgres docs and some examples online, but everything seems to indicate that this should be valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the unadorned `open_date` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

This should do it:

```
  SELECT date(open_date), COUNT(*)
    FROM incidents
GROUP BY date(open_date)
ORDER BY date(open_date);
```

This would also work (though I prefer not to use integers to refer to columns for maintenance reasons):

```
  SELECT date(open_date), COUNT(*)
    FROM incidents
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I can't believe I didn't realize this. >_<

Comment: Hey, not to worry; it happens to us all. We pick up and move on to tackling bigger and better bugs :D

Answer (score 1):

"open_date" is not in your select list, "date(open_date)" is.

Either of these will work:

> order by date(open_date)
>
> order by 1

You can also name your columns in the select statement, and then refer to that alias:

> select date(open_date) "alias"   ...   order by alias

Some databases require the keyword, AS, before the alias in your select.